# Compiling search patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have to search for a pattern either inside the content of a variable or inside a data file. Below is the code I have so far:

```
import re

UserSpecifiedPattern = "segfault"

# find every instance of a user specified pattern
pattern =  re.compile( rb'(\.\W+)?([^.]?segfault[^.]*?\.)',
                       re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )
```

My problem is, how does one specify a variable to "re.compile".  Meaning, I'm storing the actual pattern to be searched into a variable. And I'm then giving that variable to re.compile. The below is what I presume should work, but it isn't:

```
import re

UserSpecifiedPattern = "segfault"

# find every instance of a user specified pattern
pattern =  re.compile( rb'(\.\W+)?([^.]?UserSpecifiedPattern[^.]*?\.)',
                       re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )
```

I'm guessing this should be it?

```
import re

UserSpecifiedPattern = "segfault"

# find every instance of a user specified pattern
pattern =  re.compile( rb'(\.\W+)?([^.]?{UserSpecifiedPattern}[^.]*?\.)',
                       re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searching a regex with a `bytes` input works, but of course your variable name is treated literally.

You have to inject your variable, for instance by using `format` on the string, then encode to bytes (`bytes` object doesn't have `format` so encode it afterwards (you cannot use `b` prefix here):

```
pattern =  re.compile(r'(\.\W+)?([^.]?{}[^.]*?\.)'.format(UserSpecifiedPattern).encode(),
                   re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE )
```

notes:

- it works for this particular pattern which doesn't make use of `{}` to repeat expressions. If you have to use that, double the braces: ex: `{{1,5}}`
- depending on the pattern you're passing, you may need to use `re.escape` on it if you want regex to see it literally (it doesn't matter much with words)